# Gerrit GC vs Git GC - or maybe Both?

Tags: gerrit

We are running gerrit 2.10.7, and we've been having occasional problems with corrupted objects not being repaired by gerrit gc, even though git gc repairs them fine.

On the other hand, I read that gerrit gc creates bitmaps which optimize other gerrit operations.

So I'm wondering if it wouldn't make sense to run both, especially since gerrit gc doesn't notify me on failures. The only way to confirm gerrit gc ran is to examine the logs.

If I do run both, should I run git gc first, then gerrit gc, or the other way around?

So, what to you do?

Also posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/XXsoBhqQUiY

Answer (score 1):

If you have corrupted objects which `gerrit gc` cannot fix, but `git gc` can, I wonder if it would be worth creating an issue ticket for [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/) (Gerrit uses JGit internally). But before doing that, I would suggest to update Gerrit to the most recent version and see if the issue still exists there.

Basically, running Gerrit gc on a regular basis is the [suggested way](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/repo-discuss/BlVlGw6vVk4). You can [configure](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#gc) your Gerrit instance to run it automatically.

Comment: The most recent version is 2.11.x, which makes a variety of substantive changes to the UI and also seems to have a bad community rep. Updating something like that for 250 users is not something to be done lightly. Nobody just walks into Mordor...

Meanwhile, the scheduled gerrit gc on 2.10.7 is just not very reliable...